# Parsing XML with French characters in Android

Tags: android

I am currently parsing a XML file from the assets folder of my Android Project. The XML contains French characters. I am using XMLPullParser to parse the XML. But the french characters are showing like ?. Please Help me to overcome this problem. Here is my code for the parser

```
public class QuestionsXmlParser {

// We don't use name spaces
private static final String ns = null;

private HashMap<Integer, Questions> questions= new HashMap<Integer, Questions>();
private String questionLevel;

public QuestionsXmlParser(String questionLevel) {
    this.questionLevel = questionLevel;
}

public HashMap<Integer, Questions> parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {     
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);

        parser.setInput(in, "UTF-8");
        parser.nextTag();
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

private HashMap<Integer, Questions> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rallyecoop");

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        // Starts by looking for the entry tag

        if (name.equals("quizquestion")) {
            readQuestions(parser);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    } 
    return questions;
}

private void readQuestions(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "quizquestion");

    int id = 0;
    String question = null, category = null, level = null;

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("id")) {
            id = Integer.parseInt(readId(parser));
        } else if (name.equals("question")) {
            question = readQuestion(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("category")) {
            category = readCategory(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("level")) {
            level = readLevel(parser);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }


    if(level.equals(questionLevel)){
        Questions singleQuestion = new Questions();
        singleQuestion.setId(id);
        singleQuestion.setQuestion(question);
        singleQuestion.setCategory(category);
        singleQuestion.setLevel(level);
        System.out.println("id->"+id+"category "+category);
        questions.put(id, singleQuestion);
        System.out.println("Questions Size "+questions.size());
    }

    return;
}

private String readId(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "id");
    String id = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "id");
    return id;
}

private String readQuestion(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "question");
    String question = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "question");
    return question;
}

private String readCategory(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "category");
    String category = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "category");
    return category;
}

private String readLevel(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "level");
    String level = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "level");
    return level;
}

private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String result = "";
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    return result;
}

private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int depth = 1;
    while (depth != 0) {
        switch (parser.next()) {
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            depth--;
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            depth++;
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

}

And this is how i access the XML file from the assets folder

```
questionsXmlParser.parse(getResources().getAssets().open("question.xml"));
```

This is the header of the XML which i am trying to parse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

Comment: In what coding is the XML file? eg: UTF-8; ISO-8859-1?

Comment: Don't think it has anything to do with the parser, probably more to do with where the data is being displayed.

Comment: @Jeshurun Thank you for your response. Can you please tell me what the change which i can make in the displaying part. I am using Textview to display all the contents which are being parsed from the XML.

Comment: You will have to use the HTML.fromHtml() method. Something like `yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(xmlParsedString);`